# Laravel 5 custom validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, registration

I am a beginner in Laravel 5. Basically I have two tables, users and teams tables. I used the built in register feature and made changes to it. Before a user can register, he must know the team name (dropdown) where he belongs as well as the team code. If the team code does not match with the team name he selected, it will simply show a validation error. How am I suppose to reference the input (team name) in the validation rule for team code? I have heard about the exists validation rule but I think a custom one is the right one to use.

In my registrar.php:

```
public function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'username' => 'required|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
        'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'team_id' => 'required',
        // 'team_code' => don't know what to put here.
    ]);
}
```

I googled Laravel's custom validation and seems it's not enough for me to grasp how this will work. Can someone help me with this one? Would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the exists validator with the extended format that allows where clauses, and pass your `team_id` to make sure the id and code exist in the same row:

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
'team_id' => 'required',
'team_code' => 'exists:teams,code,team_id,' . Input::get('team_id')
```

This will check that `team_code` exists in the teams table in a row where `team_id` matches the id given as input.

You could use a custom validator but I don't think it would add much to your application - this is not really a piece of logic specific to your application that will be re-used. Any custom validator would still require you to append the `team_id` from the user to the validation string, which is not a totally clean approach.

You might even consider moving this type of application specific logic check to after the validator - it seems the intent of the validators is mostly to check the input against some static conditions to check that it is sane. There is not a lot of database interaction that can happen in the provided validators, only `exists` and `unique`.

Source: [Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation)